# JSON to Dropdown in React - response.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, get

I am following the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-leaf-2hupv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

The example works in my React project but when I try to adapt it to values from my database, I get the error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.data.map is not a function

My JSON is simple

```
categories: 
0:  
Id: "22"
Name:   "Strategy"
1:  
Id: "19"
Name:   "Sports"
2:  
Id: "27"
Name:   "Branding"
```

I have adapted the code to fit my JSON as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class TestDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            display: "",
            titles: [],
            errorMsg: ''
        };
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
        }));
    }

    componentDidMount = (e) => {
        axios.get("https://mysite/devapi/categories.php").then((response) =>
            this.setState({
                titles: response.data.map(({ Name }) => Name), /*error*/
                display:
                    response.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.length)].title
            })
        );
    };

    render() {
        const { display, titles } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <select defaultValue={display}>
                    {titles.map((Name) => (
                        <option key={Name} value={Name}>
                            {Name}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have considered whether I am making a mistake by reading the wrong JSON value by not accessing 'categories' or whether this has something to do with map / list.
I would only need the Name values to populate the Option with.

Kind thanks from a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do something like

```
response?.data?.map(({ Name }) => Name)
```

or

```
response && responese.data && response.data.map((element, index) => {
   console.log('My data', element) // here you should see your data
})
```

To make sure, that we have that data

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, unfortunately it get error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _response$data.map is not a function

Comment: I just updated my answer please check this out

Answer (score 0):

By checking length of response response.data.map is not a function error will be removed

```
response.data.length > 0 && response.data.map((element, index) => {
console.log('My data', element) // here you should see your data
})
```